# Need help categorizing data into 2 groups according to multiple columns in R?

Tags: r, categorical-data

I have 6 columns of numeric and non numeric data in R as follows:

```
     V1  V2      V3      V4              V5        V6
 1   N abc       M       'apple'         2         60 
 2   C pqr       R       'banana'        3        70
 3   N pqr       M       'tomato'        1         50
 4   D abc       A       'cheese'        2         300
 5   D uio       R       'potato'        1          60
 6   C xyz       A        'milk'         5          200
 7   N gef       M        'milk'         6          500
 8   D wvy       A        'yogurt'       1          300
 9   C abc       A        'apple'        7          100
 10  C abc       R        'potato'        8         100
```

I want to group the data into 2 groups according to some characteristics using the 6 columns.

For example: Grocery category: if V1= 'N' or V1=C and V3='M' and V4= 'apple' or V4= 'banana' or V4 = 'potato'or V4= 'tomato' and if V1='N' it is necessary to consider  V6 <=100$ etc
Milk Category = whatever does not belong to grocery.

How would I do it?

I tried using the case_when but it didn't work.

Comment: I am convinced that the formatting way is better, so I will undo your edit. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557 Please review for any info which got lost.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `case_when`. I'm not sure what you tried that didn't work, please let me know if I can clarify further.

You can use `%in%` to see if a particular letter or word is contained in a vector, as alternative to having multiple "OR" operations.

The final `TRUE` case will be considered if there are no `TRUE` evaluations earlier in the `case_when` statement.

**Edit**: Added additional logic that would consider `V6` in the event that `V1` is "N".

```
df %>%
  mutate(category = case_when(
    (V1 == "C" | (V1 == "N" & V6 <= 100)) & 
      V3 == "M" & 
      V4 %in% c("apple", "banana", "potato", "tomato") ~ "grocery",
    TRUE ~ "milk"
  ))
```

**Output**

```
   V1  V2 V3     V4 V5  V6 category
1   N abc  M  apple  2  60  grocery
2   C pqr  R banana  3 700     milk
3   N pqr  M tomato  1  50  grocery
4   D abc  A cheese  2 300     milk
5   D uio  R potato  1  60     milk
6   C xyz  A   milk  5  20     milk
7   N gef  M   milk  6 500     milk
8   D wvy  A yogurt  1  30     milk
9   C abc  A  apple  7 600     milk
10  C abc  R potato  8 400     milk
```

Comment: it didn't work for the columns tha are numerical; for example I have also a condition that says V6 need to be <=100$ so that I can include it in the grocery category

Comment: @inançpsycho If you could, modify your post with an example that considers numerical columns, and I'll edit my answer further to match what you need. It might help to understand better what "didn't work". Your example above does not use numeric columns.

Comment: Thank you for the notice I did edit it

Comment: @inançpsycho See edited answer. You can make your logic more complex as needed. For example, you can categorize as "grocery" if `V1` is "C" *OR* `V1` is "N" *AND* `V6` is below or equal to 100. Let me know if this is what you had in mind. If not, it might help if you could clarify further with examples of different situations where this might not meet your needs.

Comment: Also, depending on what your ultimate goal is, there are other approaches. For example, if you have a large number of different categories, with different criteria, you can consider a separate look up table and doing a "fuzzy join" between your data and the look up table.

Comment: Thank you so much. You got me. Yes normally i have a large data; i just tried to minimize it in this exmple and I have for now 10 criteria trying to segment the different clients of th Mall .How can I use "fuzzy join"?

Comment: For 10 criteria, and mutually exclusive categories, using `case_when` may be a reasonable option. If you had hundreds of different combinations for different categories, or they weren't mutually exclusive (and could result in multiple rows added), then a look up table and join can be an option. With that direction, you create a new data.frame that has the same column names, and for continuous variables divide into two (low/high) for a range perhaps. Also add column for "category". Then some type of "fuzzy join" (using `data.table` faster than `fuzzy_join` package) join your data...

Comment: ...with the look up table. A fuzzy join would allow you to join - say - the `V6` value where it falls between the range low/high in the look up table. When you do the join, it will add the `category` column to your data. Hope this is helpful. You can always consider a new question if you go down that route.

Comment: @ben check your code  as [2] , [5], [9] and [10] gives 'milk' category

Comment: @Rfanatic I understand - a lot depends on how you interpret the logic with "AND" and "OR" (without grouping parentheses, there could be room for interpretation). Also, I included `V3` in my `case_when` logic which gives a different result than yours. Since the post was edited a few times, there may be differences there too...

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the nicest way but I would use `ifelse()`

Sample code:

```
category<-0
category<-ifelse((df$V1=="N" | df$V1=="C") & (df$V4=="apple" |  df$V4=="banana" | df$V4=="potato" | df$V4=="tomato"), "Grocery", "Milk")
category<-as.data.frame(category)
                         
  ex<-cbind(category,df)
  ex
```

Output:

```
   category V1  V2 V3       V4 V5  V6
1   Grocery  N abc  M    apple  2  60
2   Grocery  C pqr  R   banana  3 700
3   Grocery  N pqr  M   tomato  1  50
4      Milk  D abc  A   cheese  2 300
5      Milk  D uio  R   potato  1  60
6      Milk  C xyz  A     milk  5  20
7      Milk  N gef  M     milk  6 500
8      Milk  D wvy  A youghurt  1  30
9   Grocery  C abc  A    apple  7 600
10  Grocery  C abc  R   potato  8 400
```